# consulta no entrega ningun dato al relacionar dos campos con un "AND"

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día
estoy trabajando en obtener información desde una ficha clínica.

Estas son las tablas que estoy tratando de relacionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla *General_persona* tiene datos generales de los usuarios,
*Atencion_Atecon* contiene información de la citación,
*Atencion_AteconValor* contiene información sobre la atención realizada y la tabla *Atencion_IItem* es donde se almacena la información de la atención realizada.

Por ejemplo, en un ítem se guarda el valor del colesterol y en otro el del azúcar en sangre.
Y lo que necesito es obtener la nómina rutificada de los usuarios que tengan estos dos ítems al mismo tiempo.

```
SELECT     Atencion_AteConValor.id_item, Atencion_Item.Item, General_Persona.Rut, General_Persona.Nombre, 
           Atencion_AteCon.id_citacion, Atencion_AteCon.Fecha, Atencion_AteConValor.Valor
FROM       Atencion_AteCon INNER JOIN
           Atencion_AteConValor ON Atencion_AteCon.id_AteCon = 
           Atencion_AteConValor.id_AteCon INNER JOIN
           Atencion_Item ON Atencion_AteConValor.id_item = Atencion_Item.id_item INNER JOIN
           General_Persona ON Atencion_AteConValor.id_persona = General_Persona.id_Persona
WHERE     Atencion_Item.id_item= 2628 and Atencion_Item.id_item= 2629
          and YEAR( Atencion_AteCon.Fecha)> 2020
```

Uso esa query y no arroja información.
Agradecería si alguien me puede orientar, no logro ver donde esta el error.

Answer (score 0):

no me deja comentar aun, pero sin ver mucho ya falla la logica del where

Atencion_Item.id_item= 2628 and Atencion_Item.id_item= 2629
nunca devuelve filas.

suerte